# Yajra/JQuery datatable exporting child rows into CSV

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, datatables

I have a table with too much data. What I did was I added it as child rows to in order view. But when I want to export the contents of the table, the child rows are not included. Tried several solutions but none is working.

Here is my table

[image]

When I do export the data in the excel is only this one

[image]

I used the simple way of putting the buttons on the front end via

```
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                      {
                      extend: 'csv',
                      text: 'Export to CSV',
                      className: 'btn btn-default',
                      charset: 'utf-8',
                      fieldSeparator: ',',
                      bom: true,
                      filename: 'Corporates',
                      exportOptions: {
                          columns: ':not(.notexport)'
                      },}
                    ],
```

In my controller, I simply return datatables function of yajra.

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $corporate = Corporate::all();
        if($request->ajax()){
            return Datatables::of($corporate)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('created_at', function ($row) {
                return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row->created_at)->format('M d, Y');
            })
            ->addColumn('buttons', function ($row) {
                return '<a href="'.route('admin.corporate.edit',$row->id).'" class="btn btn-primary"> Update</a> &nbsp; <button onclick="deleteCorporate('.$row->id.')" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>';
            })
            ->rawColumns(['buttons'])
            ->make(true);
        }
        return view('corporate.index');
    }
```

Does anyone know what I missed or what to do? Thanks in advance.